# Error while registering plugin "Missing or undefined handler"

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi.js

I am creating a sample nodejs application. In which I have added one plugin. When I try to execute application I get error "Missing or undefined handler".

My plugin file

```
exports.plugin = {
    name: "test plugin",
    version: '0.0.1',
    register: async function (server: Hapi.Server, options) {
        try {
           routes(server);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my route file:

```
export default function (server: Hapi.Server) {
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: `/test/app`,
        config: contoller.testController()
    })
}
```

In controller I have added following code

```
export class ControllerTest{

    public async testController(): Hapi.RouteOptions {
        return {
            handler: async (request, h) => {
                try {
                    return "hello";
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                }
            },
            tags:["GET"]
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to debug the code. When I reach at route file I get instance of ControllerTest class and method is also available over there even though getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with controller. Due to async method it was not working. After removing async from method signature it works.

```
public testController(): Hapi.RouteOptions {
        return {
            handler: async (request, h) => {
                try {
                    return "hello";
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                }
            },
            tags:["GET"]
        }
    }
```